# Disable Quick Edit in Golang

Tags: windows, go, cmd

I want to disable quick edit mode in Golang to avoid my terminal getting block by a user click.

For that I use the official library [golang.org/x/sys/windows](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#GetConsoleMode).
I want to disable QUICK_EDIT_MODE & enable EXTENDED_FLAGS as describe by [the official microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode). When I use the code snippet below, I'm getting an error at set `The parameter is incorrect.`

I'm running it in CMD or Powershell I get the same error there. And I don't really know what is missing there. I'm on Windows 10 v20H2 19042.1586 if that matters.

Code Snippet

```
import (
    "os"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

...

func SetupConsole() {
    winConsole := windows.Handle(os.Stdout.Fd())

    var mode uint32
    err := windows.GetConsoleMode(winConsole, &mode)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%d", mode) <--- 3

    // Disable this mode
    mode &^= windows.ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE

    // Enable this mode
    mode |= windows.ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS

    log.Printf("%d", mode) <--- 131
    err = windows.SetConsoleMode(winConsole, mode)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err) <--- This fails: The parameter is incorrect.
    }
}
```

EDIT: See Answer below

```
func SetupConsole() {
    winConsole := windows.Handle(os.Stdin.Fd()) <--- Was wrong here

    var mode uint32
    err := windows.GetConsoleMode(winConsole, &mode)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%d", mode)

    // Disable this mode
    mode &^= windows.ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE

    // Enable this mode
    mode |= windows.ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS

    log.Printf("%d", mode)
    err = windows.SetConsoleMode(winConsole, mode)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues.

First you should be using Stdin instead of Stdout. You can also just pass in windows.Stdin into the Get/SetConsole mode and skip the Fd() call and casting.

Second, to disable it you just need to toggle the windows.ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE flag.

The combination of using Stdout & ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS together is what resulted in the error returing from SetConsoleMode

Comment: The Stdin was the issue there ! Thanks a lot